JS: Accessing paths on loaded SVG image, to change colours, before drawing to document
I have an svg that has multiple paths  inside that I want to manipulate the colours before drawing into the document:
In the SVG I have
  <path id="pathHair01" ....
 <path id="pathBody01" ....
 <path id="pathMain01" ......

and IM loading this with
    let img= new Image()
    img.id = 'myImg'
    img.src = 'myImage.svg'

before I draw using
ctx.drawImage(img, leftPoint, topPoint, newWidth, newHeight)

I want to manipulate the colours of my paths . g
How can I access the paths of .img  before drawint it to the document?
(Ie I dont think I can use  document.getElementById(img.id)  since it hasnt yet been drawn to the document ?

ctx.drawImage is a <canvas> so it looks like you draw an SVG (vectors) on a CANVAS (pixels) For what purpose? You can load an external SVG and inject it into the HTML document see: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Hiya.  Yes exactly that, IM using the svg to draw vectors on my canvas.  I am using multiple ctx to build up an imaged of ctx code and svg layers. Much like NFT images . SO its not so much an html document with images inline

If you need to manipulate an external SVG file you would first need to to read and parse its content. E.g by using fetch() for data retrieval and  new DOMParser() for parsing - then you would need to create a new image src via a new data URL that could be rendered to canvas.

Can the new image src be an updated svg xml in memory rather than a URL file location. as I dont want to resave a new file, I want to load it , parse it ,edit it, then draw it.   Cheers

A dataURL doesn't create a new file location - so it's in memory. Please add a minimal reproducible example  to your question

You can directly write script in you svg file like this:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Uploaded to: SVG Repo, www.svgrepo.com, Generator: SVG Repo Mixer Tools -->
<svg width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" class="icon"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="try1" d="M827.1 782l-70.3 23.3c1.6 5.1 2.4 10.5 2.4 16.1 0 7.7-1.6 15-4.5 21.7l68.3 28.6c6.6-15.4 10.3-32.4 10.3-50.3 0-13.8-2.2-27-6.2-39.4z" fill="#FFFFFF" /><path d="M683.9 771.8l-28.6-68.3c-33.9 14.4-60.3 43.1-71.8 78.5l70.3 23.3c4.7-15.1 15.8-27.3 30.1-33.5zM756.9 805.2l70.3-23.3c-12.5-38.7-42.9-69.4-81.5-82.2L722.4 770c16.4 5.5 29.3 18.7 34.5 35.2zM655.8 843l-68.3 28.6c13.1 30.6 37.7 55 68.4 67.9l28.6-68.3c-12.8-5.3-23.1-15.5-28.7-28.2zM721.7 872.8L745 943c35.2-11.5 63.6-37.7 78.1-71.4L754.8 843c-6.2 14.1-18.2 25-33.1 29.8z" fill="#FFACC2" /><path d="M705.3 767.3c6 0 11.7 1 17 2.8l23.3-70.3c-12.7-4.2-26.2-6.5-40.3-6.5-17.8 0-34.7 3.6-50.1 10.2l28.6 68.3c6.6-2.9 13.9-4.5 21.5-4.5zM705.3 875.3c-7.3 0-14.3-1.5-20.7-4.1L656 939.5c15.2 6.3 31.8 9.9 49.3 9.9 13.9 0 27.2-2.2 39.7-6.3l-23.3-70.3c-5.1 1.6-10.7 2.5-16.4 2.5zM651.3 821.3c0-5.6 0.9-11 2.4-16.1L583.5 782c-4 12.4-6.2 25.6-6.2 39.4 0 17.8 3.7 34.8 10.3 50.3l68.3-28.6c-3-6.7-4.6-14.1-4.6-21.8z" fill="#FFFFFF" /><path d="M948.4 702.6c-13.8 0-20.7-9.8-25.7-17-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2s-7.5 3-12.7 10.2c-5.1 7.2-12 17-25.7 17s-20.7-9.8-25.7-17c-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2-5 0-7.5 3-12.7 10.2-5.1 7.2-12 17-25.7 17-13.8 0-20.7-9.8-25.7-17-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8 8-8c13.8 0 20.7 9.8 25.7 17 5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 5 0 7.5-3 12.7-10.2 5.1-7.2 12-17 25.7-17 13.8 0 20.7 9.8 25.7 17 5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 5 0 7.5-3 12.7-10.2 5.1-7.2 12-17 25.7-17s20.7 9.8 25.7 17c5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8s-3.6 8-8 8zM948.4 652.6c-13.8 0-20.7-9.8-25.7-17-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2s-7.5 3-12.7 10.2c-5.1 7.2-12 17-25.7 17s-20.7-9.8-25.7-17c-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2-5 0-7.5 3-12.7 10.2-5.1 7.2-12 17-25.7 17-13.8 0-20.7-9.8-25.7-17-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8 8-8c13.8 0 20.7 9.8 25.7 17 5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 5 0 7.5-3 12.7-10.2 5.1-7.2 12-17 25.7-17 13.8 0 20.7 9.8 25.7 17 5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 5 0 7.5-3 12.7-10.2 5.1-7.2 12-17 25.7-17s20.7 9.8 25.7 17c5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8s-3.6 8-8 8zM239.4 280.6c-12.9 0-19.2-10.1-23.8-17.4-4.3-6.9-6.5-9.9-10.2-9.9s-5.9 3-10.2 9.9c-4.6 7.3-10.9 17.4-23.8 17.4s-19.2-10.1-23.8-17.4c-4.3-6.9-6.5-9.9-10.2-9.9s-5.9 3-10.2 9.9c-4.6 7.3-10.9 17.4-23.8 17.4s-19.2-10.1-23.8-17.4c-4.3-6.9-6.5-9.9-10.2-9.9-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8 8-8c12.9 0 19.2 10.1 23.8 17.4 4.3 6.9 6.5 9.9 10.2 9.9s5.9-3 10.2-9.9c4.6-7.3 10.9-17.4 23.8-17.4s19.2 10.1 23.8 17.4c4.3 6.9 6.5 9.9 10.2 9.9 3.7 0 5.9-3 10.2-9.9 4.6-7.3 10.9-17.4 23.8-17.4s19.2 10.1 23.8 17.4c4.3 6.9 6.5 9.9 10.2 9.9 4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8s-3.6 8-8 8zM261.3 230.6c-13.8 0-20.7-9.8-25.7-17-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2s-7.5 3-12.7 10.2c-5.1 7.2-12 17-25.7 17-13.8 0-20.7-9.8-25.7-17-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2s-7.5 3-12.7 10.2c-5.1 7.2-12 17-25.7 17s-20.7-9.8-25.7-17c-5.1-7.3-7.7-10.2-12.7-10.2-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8 8-8c13.8 0 20.7 9.8 25.7 17 5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2s7.5-3 12.7-10.2c5.1-7.2 12-17 25.7-17s20.7 9.8 25.7 17c5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 5 0 7.5-3 12.7-10.2 5.1-7.2 12-17 25.7-17s20.7 9.8 25.7 17c5.1 7.3 7.7 10.2 12.7 10.2 4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8s-3.6 8-8 8z" fill="#9A2D2F" /><path d="M835.7 951.3H183.1c-44.9 0-81.7-36.8-81.7-81.7v-0.5c0-7.6 6.2-13.8 13.8-13.8h788.4c7.6 0 13.8 6.2 13.8 13.8v0.5c0 45-36.8 81.7-81.7 81.7z" fill="#DAE5FF" /><path d="M511.3 95.4c-65.5 25.8-125.5 62.6-177.6 108.2l177.6 47.6V95.4z" fill="#FFACC2" /><path d="M125.3 662.3c0 43.6 4.6 86 13.3 127h372.7V648L136.1 547.5c-7.1 37.2-10.8 75.5-10.8 114.8z" fill="#FFEB4D" /><path d="M237.7 309.7L511.3 383V251.2l-177.6-47.6c-36 31.4-68.2 67-96 106.1z" fill="#F7D4FF" /><path d="M173.3 424.9l338 90.6V383.7l-274-73.4c-25.3 35.5-46.8 74-64 114.6z" fill="#DAE5FF" /><path d="M173.3 424.9c-16.5 38.9-29.1 80-37.2 122.6L511.3 648V515.5l-338-90.6z" fill="#C0FCD0" /><path d="M502.6 108c-54.7 23-105.4 53.8-151.2 91.8l72.8 19.5c18.2-8.8 69.2-61.9 78.4-111.3zM203.6 666.3c0-17.9-4.9-56.4 1.8-92.3l-61.9-16.6c-6 34.4-9.1 69.6-9.1 104.8 0 40 4 80 11.8 119h26.2c22.4-31.9 31.2-80.9 31.2-114.9zM400.2 229.4l-63.4-17c-31.4 27.8-59.8 58.9-84.7 92.5l58.4 15.6c1.2-18.8 4-35.9 8.9-49.1 11.6-31.1 43.3-28.2 80.8-42zM185.3 419.6l93.7 25.1c6.5-4.7 30.5-17.7 30.5-107.1l-67.9-18.2c-21.9 31.6-40.8 65.2-56.3 100.2zM208.6 558.4c3.2-14.3-4.3-58.7 52.2-102L179 434.5c-14.2 34.6-25.1 70.6-32.6 107.2l62.2 16.7z" fill="#FFFFFF" /><path d="M925.4 868.7v-0.5c0-12-9.8-21.8-21.8-21.8H839c1.5-8.2 2.3-16.5 2.3-25 0-14.3-2.2-28.3-6.6-41.8-13.3-41.1-45.6-73.7-86.6-87.3-13.8-4.6-28.2-6.9-42.8-6.9-18.4 0-36.3 3.6-53.2 10.8-8 3.4-15.5 7.5-22.6 12.3l-109.4-459c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2V97.6c0-0.9-0.1-1.7-0.4-2.5-0.1-2.6-1.4-4.9-3.5-6.4-2.2-1.5-5-1.8-7.4-0.8-65.9 25.9-126.4 62.8-180 109.6-36.5 31.9-69.2 68-97.2 107.5-0.1 0.1-0.1 0.2-0.2 0.3-0.1 0.1-0.1 0.2-0.2 0.3-25.7 36.3-47.5 75.4-64.8 116.2-16.9 39.8-29.6 81.6-37.7 124.2-7.3 38.1-10.9 77.2-10.9 116.3 0 43.3 4.5 86.6 13.4 128.7 0.8 3.7 4 6.3 7.8 6.3h365.1v49.1H115.2c-12 0-21.8 9.8-21.8 21.8v0.5c0 31.1 15.9 58.6 40.1 74.7H74.3c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8s3.6 8 8 8h824c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8s-3.6-8-8-8h-13c24.2-16.1 40.1-43.6 40.1-74.7z m-100.1-47.4c0 8.5-0.9 16.8-2.6 25h-39.3l-18.5-7.8c1.6-5.6 2.4-11.3 2.4-17.2 0-3.6-0.3-7.3-0.9-10.8l33.4-11.1 21.9-7.3c2.4 9.6 3.6 19.4 3.6 29.2z m-74.7-111.1c30.1 12.3 54.2 36.5 66.2 66.8l-48.5 16-6.8 2.3c-6-13-16.4-23.5-29.3-29.7l18.4-55.4z m0.7 111.1c0 6.4-1.3 12.6-3.9 18.5-1 2.3-2.2 4.5-3.5 6.5h-77.2c-1.4-2.1-2.6-4.3-3.6-6.5-2.6-5.8-3.9-12.1-3.9-18.5 0-4.7 0.7-9.3 2.1-13.7 4-12.8 13.3-23.2 25.7-28.5 5.8-2.5 11.9-3.8 18.3-3.8 4.9 0 9.8 0.8 14.5 2.4 14 4.7 25 15.8 29.4 29.9 1.4 4.4 2.1 9.1 2.1 13.7z m-46-120c10.2 0 20.3 1.3 30.1 3.8l-18.3 55.3c-3.9-0.8-7.8-1.1-11.8-1.1-5.8 0-11.5 0.8-17 2.4L665.8 708c12.7-4.4 25.9-6.7 39.5-6.7z m-76.2 27.3c0.3-0.2 0.5-0.4 0.8-0.6 6.5-5.3 13.6-9.9 21.2-13.7l22.5 53.8c-10.8 6.4-19.3 15.9-24.6 27.2L593.8 777c7.5-19 19.8-35.6 35.3-48.4z m16.6 110l-18.5 7.8h-39.3c-1.7-8.2-2.6-16.5-2.6-25 0-9.9 1.2-19.7 3.6-29.2l44 14.5 11.4 3.8c-0.6 3.6-0.9 7.2-0.9 10.8-0.1 5.9 0.7 11.7 2.3 17.3z m-142.4-57.3H145.1c-7.8-39-11.8-79-11.8-119 0-35.2 3.1-70.4 9.1-104.8l360.9 96.7v127.1z m0-143.7l-357.9-95.9c7.5-36.6 18.4-72.7 32.6-107.2l325.3 87.2v115.9z m0-132.5l-79.6-21.3-239.4-64.2c15.5-35 34.4-68.7 56.3-100.2l262.7 70.4v115.3z m0-132.5L251 304.9c24.9-33.7 53.4-64.7 84.7-92.6l157.4 42.2 10.2 2.7v115.4z m0-131.9l-42.5-11.4-110.4-29.6c46.2-38.4 97.5-69.5 152.8-92.5v133.5z m16.4 76.1l95.9 402.3c-18.3 16-32.1 36.8-39.7 60.4-4.4 13.5-6.6 27.6-6.6 41.8 0 8.5 0.8 16.8 2.3 25h-51.9V316.8z m316 625.6H183.1c-40.6 0-73.7-33.1-73.7-73.7v-0.5c0-3.2 2.6-5.8 5.8-5.8h788.4c3.2 0 5.8 2.6 5.8 5.8v0.5c0 40.6-33.1 73.7-73.7 73.7z" fill="#9A2D2F" /><path d="M349.3 102.3m-32 0a32 32 0 1 0 64 0 32 32 0 1 0-64 0Z" fill="#FFEB4D" /><path d="M349.3 142.3c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40s17.9-40 40-40 40 17.9 40 40-17.9 40-40 40z m0-64c-13.2 0-24 10.8-24 24s10.8 24 24 24 24-10.8 24-24-10.8-24-24-24z" fill="#9A2D2F" />

<script>
document.getElementById("try1").setAttribute("fill", "black");
</script>
</svg>



Then directly change the path or other element attribute to change color.
Like:-
document.getElementById("yourID").setAttribute("fill", "color");

When I try this it never seems to find the id of the path to give me access to the path. But I believe that is because Im not able to access it yet before it is added to the document?  Im loading the svg from a separate file, and before drawing it to the canvas I want to change a few of the colours .
